# setting ContentType in AngularJs for Arabic Characters

Tags: java, angularjs, utf-8, content-type, restful-architecture

AngularJs is Changing Arabic Characters to Special Characters while calling restful Service POST method. how to resolve it

Comment: how u r sending the data in restfull api?

Comment: $http.post("services/rest/uploadService/insert", formData, {
            headers: {
           
            'Content-Type':'charset=utf-16'
            }
        }).success(function(response)

-------formData is Object type

Comment: make sure your templates have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` and also save all your angular files in UTF-8 encoding